# How to export code outputs to HTML using org-export?

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file with the following contents:

```
#+begin_src python
from datetime import datetime
return datetime.now()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 2021-10-30 17:05:27.247133
```

I want to export this file to HTML, both code and output. This can be achieved if I just add `:exports both` to the code header. But the tricky part is:

1. The org-mode exporter just evaluates the code, gets the new result (instead of the result shown in my org file), and converts it to HTML. The new output is not what I want because it runs in a new context. I want the output shown in the HTML to be **exactly** the same as the shown in the file.
2. If the code doesn't have a `#+RESULTS:` part in the org file, don't show it in the generated HTML file as well.
3. I have a lot of such org files to be converted into HTML, so it would be really great if I can change the behavior by just modifying some variables instead of changing each code block one by one.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eval` header to influence when/how to evaluate a code block (do `C-h i g(org)Evaluating Code Blocks` and scroll down to the `Limit code block evaluation` subsection to see the details). In your case you want `:eval never-export`, which is described as follows in the manual:

> Org does not evaluate the source code when exporting, yet the user can evaluate it interactively.

You can specify it per-code-block with:

```
#+begin_src python :eval never-export
...
#+end_src
```

You can specify it per-subtree with:

```
* Limit it to the current subtree
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :eval never-export
```

or you can specify it per-file with:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :eval never-export
```

You can also limit it to blocks for a specified language by using e.g. `header-args:python` instead of `header-args`.

I looked for an option that you can set globally, but I don't think one exists. The closest I found is `org-export-use-babel`: setting it to nil stops the evaluation of (all) source blocks, but unfortunately it's a bit too blunt for your purposes: it also ignores headers. So I think you'll have to be satisfied with the per-file method. If you can identify all the files of interest, you could do a batch edit of all of them to add the appropriate `#+PROPERTY:` line at the top of each. Better yet, you might want to add a `#+SETUPFILE:` line in the batch edit instead, e.g.:

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/src/org/setup.org
```

and put the `#+PROPERTY:` line in the setup file. That would be a one-time operation and from then on *every* file that includes that line would get whatever settings you put in your setup file - and if at some point you wanted to get rid of these customizations, you could make the setup file empty - or even delete it altogether, although that generates complaints in the `*Messages*` buffer.

EDIT: Here's how I tested. I created an Org mode file like this:

```org
#+SETUPFILE: ~/src/org/setup.org


* Test

#+begin_src elisp
(random)
#+end_src


#+begin_src python :results value
from random import random
return random()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0.10363433247781972
```

with the setup file containing this:

```org
#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports both :eval never-export
```

and exported it to HTML. The resulting HTML file shows this (cut and pasted directly from Firefox):

```
1. Test

(random)

from random import random
return random()

0.10363433247781972
```

so no result from the lisp code block and the same result from the python code block as in the Org mode file (i.e. the RNG was *not* exercised again, the code block was not evaluated on export). I then evaluated the lisp code block manually to get this buffer:

```org
#+SETUPFILE: ~/src/org/setup.org


* Test

#+begin_src elisp
(random)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 1890415366607963977


#+begin_src python :results value
from random import random
return random()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0.10363433247781972
```

I saved the buffer and exported again to get this in Firefox:

```
1. Test

(random)

1890415366607963977

from random import random
return random()

0.10363433247781972
```

The resulting HTML contains exactly the same results as the Org mode file does: the code blocks do not get reevaluated. It seems to me that that's exactly what you asked for.

And a couple of things that you might have missed:

- Make sure that the `:exports both` header is present.
- Make sure that you save the buffer in the file before exporting.
- Make sure that if you add `#+PROPERTY:`  or `#+SETUPFILE:`  lines in the buffer, you restart Org mode on the buffer by pressing `C-c C-c` on one of those lines (any keyword line will do, actually).

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, but it doesn't solve all of my problems. Maybe I'm not clear enough in my original post. I said that `I want the output shown in the HTML to be exactly the same as the org file`, which means I want the code **along with the result evaluated in my org file** to be shown in the HTML. In other words, the result should not be evaluated every time the file is converted, the result should be **taken directly from the org file**. If the org file doesn't contain the `#+RESULS:` part, then don't show it in the HTML file, either. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you keep the `:exports both` (if not, you should)? In my experiments, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: Yes, it worked after adding `:exports both`, thanks!